# Calling equals on string literal

Tags: java, string, comparison

I just was tidying my code a bit and there was this piece:

```
String saving = getValue();
if(saving != null && saving.equals("true")){
   // do something
}
```

Then I thought of doing it the other way around to get rid of the checking for `null`:

```
if("true".equals(saving)){
   // do something
}
```

It definitely works, but **is this safe** to do so? I mean string literals are stored in a common pool, while string object create by `new` are on the heap. But strings in the constant pool are also objects, right?

But still it doesn't seem like the right thing to do, even though it makes the code shorter.

Comment: _Safe_ in what sense?

Comment: What you're doing is what a lot of people here have recommended.  Yes, strings in the constant pool are objects, and using `.equals` on one does what you'd expect.  So this is OK, and it's safe.

Comment: String literals always create objects on the heap.  It doesn't matter where you put them.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well I thought of it as that if the String is already in the pool, then I can be sure that the object is already create. So can't it happen that the object won't be created before the method is called..

Comment: I suggested a new title for your question - Is this a safe way to avoid NullPointerExecption or NPE when handling String ? Please accept if you think it makes sense. Btw, Thanks for this good question.

Comment: No, you are guaranteed that the String literal is always referencing an existing object.

Comment: @Trojan.ZBOT The original title is better.  This is EXACTLY about calling `equals` on a String literal.  But your proposed title could be about almost any code that has Strings in it, and could lead to a null pointer exception.  Please, OP, don't change the title.

Comment: Oh, bother, I see I was too late.

Comment: @DavidWallace oh well, me too, I didn't accept that edit..

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Alright, thanks for reassurance!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is safe - and as you have seen, a good way of avoiding null pointers.

You mention the use of `new` for Strings. Many java static code analysis tools will recommend always using literals over `new String("foo");`.

Edit:

If you wanted, you could even just use:

```
if (Boolean.valueOf(saving)) {
    ...
}
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)), passing `null` will return `false`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, why didn't I think of that.. although this might be a bit slower :)

Comment: Runtime exceptions are thrown for a reason. Hiding that might cause more serious problems.

Comment: True, but it depends on the desired behavior. If a `null` string should equate to `false` then the above is fine. In reality, the variable should be a `boolean` anyway

Answer (score 29):

Just to ensure there is a fully balanced set of answers to this question I would like to post a different opinion.

I think this mechanism is foolish.

If you have a `null` you should know as soon as it happens - hiding it will just postpone its discovery. If the `null` is not an exception, replace it with something else.

Taking this approach will fortify your code with what is called *defensive programming* where your mistakes are discovered **as soon as possible** rather than covered up until everything falls apart.

In summary - `NullPointerException` is your friend. You should use it to find mistakes in your code. It is **very** easy to use a *Empty* object such as `Collections.emptySet()` once you have determined that the `null` is not an exception.

Using the Yoda technique out of habit will inevitably hide errors you do not mean to hide. **Not** using it will expose errors much earlier. To me that is sufficient argument to not use it - ever.

To me - using

```
if(saving != null && saving.equals("true")){
```

means that I actually want to allow `savings` to be `null` and it is an acceptable situation - using

```
if("true".equals(saving)){
```

merely hides that deliberate choice in a way that could become a bad habit.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! As you said `it means that I actually want to allow savings to be null`. I still find it much more clear when others might read your code. I posted the question because I never saw it anywhere and on one side it seemed quite elegant on the other like an antipattern..

Comment: Collections.emptySet() is a neutral element not a Null-Object. It is like the 1 in multiplication or the 0 in addtion. A Null-Object may introduce other behaviour of the system, a neutral element does not. The other statements I fully support: To avoid null use either null-Objects or neutral elements.

Comment: what about `Objects.equals()`? I think in a situation that allows null values, I would default to that.

Answer (score 11):

I disagree with some of the answers. Sometimes you **do** want to know if your variable is `null`. It might be an indication that something bad is happening in your code and you might want to reconsider your logic.

I don't like to do `if ("someString".equals(myString));` because I **do** want to know if `myString` is `null` and maybe handle it or change my logic to prevent similar situations.

Imagine you have an array of objects that was miscalculated due to some bug:

```
myStrings = {..., ..., null, null, ...};
```

Then you want to perform some operations on the *objects* of the array, and you'll have:

```
if ("myString".equals(myObjArray[i])) { ... }
```

You won't get `NullPointerException` and you might think that you performed the operation on all the *objects* in the array, and you'll never know that you miscalculated it because you hide the exception. Whereas if you had:

```
if (myObjArray[i].equals("myString")) { ... }
```

You'll get an *NPE* and you'll know something is wrong in the array, and you might want to fix this or handle it in another way.

Answer (score 8):

It's called yoda conditions (putting a constant before a variable in a comparison) can be considered like bad practise, maybe for someone much less readable (like me).

But sometimes using yoda condition makes the code more "comprehensible" `->` you don't need to put extra null check in front of it and it efficiently differentiates block of code from case where null is strongly forbidden.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the terminology. I don't think it's widely thought of as a bad practice, though -- more of an unfortunate consequence of the language. Sure, it's a bit more awkward to read, but you get used to it -- as you do the other weirdnesses of any programming language.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that the practice goes back at least as far as C, where it's used to guard against `=` vs `==` typos. C is weakly typed, so you can do `if (myInt = 4)`. This assigns `myInt` the value `4` and then uses that in the condition (where it's a true value). The programmer _probably_ meant `if (myInt == 4)`, but the compiler doesn't know that. On the other hand `if (4 = myInt)` fails (you can't assign a new value to `4`), which tells the programmer that they meant to type `if (4 == myInt)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
if("true".equals(saving)){
   // do something
}
```

This is very safe and good practice. String "true" will never be null. So you will never compare your String to null. This piece of code is perfectly fine

Answer (score 4):

Sorry but I cannot agree on that issue.

If you use the constant first you support structures that veil    programming errors. And one should only produce code either

1. to add functionality,
2. fix an programming error
3. or trying to support structures to avoid programming errors (like
   design patterns).

On top you have a weak assertion about the variable. Following code is always forced to check for null values as well.

If you have to deal with null values from other modules your task is to map them into proper representations in your domain model as early as possible.

In your own code avoid null as parameter or return value, so there won't be any null-checks neccessary anymore, the suggested piece of code included.

You see, this subject is more about avoiding null than accepting it to conquer your code.

Comment: Just an advice: It would be nice if you could structurize your post with paragraphs - especially if you write such long texts. Makes it more readable ;)

Comment: I followed your advice

Answer (score 3):

The format of putting the literal first avoids the potential NPE and will always be false for `"literal".equals(null)`.

This is because a "literal" expression *always* evaluates to a String object (and is thus never null) and `String.equals(obj)` checks to see if the *other* object is a null (via `asinstanceof`). An object *is* an object - no need to worry bout the "heap".

It's good practice to have a null-guard in [an equals implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) as `null.equals(null)` is *not* permissible: "The equals method implements an equivalence relation on *non-null* object references"

Here is the [String.equals the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (for OpenJDK):

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        // ..
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if ("true".equals(saving))
```

is perfectly "save" and recommended by dummy product as SonarLint and any other advisors that establish this "well" thinked rule that your chief request that you follow.

I say stupid and my explanation is the following.

What happens if you have following code

```
if (!saving.equals("true"))
    {
    if (saving.length() > 10)
        {
        // do something
        }
    }
```

You can use following advised code

```
if (!"true".equals(saving))
    {
    if (saving.length() > 10)
        {
        // do something
        }
    }
```

But when your code is deployed on production, the program will crash on `length()` function if saving variable has not been initialized and contains NULL.

You have changing your code to avoid `NullPointerException` on `equals()` function but your program will return another `NullPointerException` on `length()` function !

The good reaction is to stop to use String literal tip and to analyze code to find a perfect solution as in the following example.

```
if (saving != null)
    {
    if (!saving.equals("true"))
        {
        if (saving.length() > 10)
            {
            // do something
            }
        }
    }
```

or

```
if (saving == null) saving = "";

if (!saving.equals("true"))
    {
    if (saving.length() > 10)
        {
        // do something
        }
    }
```

Is is perhaps verbose but if you will use Java for programming it is the price to pay.

Using String literal equals() method to avoid `NullPointerException` has the following disadvantages

1. the solution is tricky
2. the code is not naturally readable for human
3. equality will not crash but another part of program will continue to
   crash
4. code become quickly difficult to read if this tips is used for
   lower() and greater() functions (example: if ('USA'.greater(sCode)))
5. give a false impression that the code is safe