# How do I turn an input String's characters to lowercase?

Tags: java

I am trying to create the following program in which I need to turn the input String's characters into lowercase to ease my work.

I tried using toLowerCase(); first but it didn't work. Then I tried using toLowerCase(locale); and yet I have not succeeded.

```
public static void  Mensuration() {
    Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
    Scanner inputz = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which kind of shape's formula would you like to find out.2D or 3D?");
    char dimension = inputz.nextLine().charAt(0);
    if(dimension == '2') {System.out.println("Okay so which shape?");
    String dimensiond = inputz.nextLine().toLowerCase(locale);
    if(dimensiond == "rectangle") {System.out.println("Area = length x breadth\nPerimeter = 2(length + breadth)");}
        }
        }
```

I expected the program to give the accurate output but the thing that happens is that there is no output actually!!

Comment: there is nothing wrong with how you put your input to lowerCase, just your comparison, as Guy points out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use equals to compare strings. I think this causing the error

```
"rectangle".equals(dimensiond)
```

Comment: a better approach is to call the equals method on the String literal

Comment: why would that be a better approach?

Comment: @Alan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385179/calling-equals-on-string-literal

Comment: To prevent NPE @Alan `null.equals("")` vs `"".equals(null)`.

Comment: there is also `equalsIgnoreCase`