# How should I write 'else' statement in this code if I want to terminate the code after user gives input as 'n/N'?

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

> I am trying to perform arithmetic operations by taking numbers as user input,I want to run the code continuously till user says no.
> How should I write 'else' statement in this code if I want to terminate the code after user gives input as 'n/N'?

````
    import java.util.*;
    
    class FirstExample{
        static void arithmetic(){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            while(true){
            System.out.println("\nDo u want to perform the arithmetic operations? (Y/N): ");
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            
            if(input=="y"||input=="Y")
            sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
            double first = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
            double second = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Addition of the two number is: "+(first+second));
            System.out.println("Subtraction of the two number is: "+(first-second));
            System.out.println("Multiplication of the two number is: "+(first*second));
            System.out.println("Division of the two number is: "+(first/second));
            sc.nextLine();
            
            }
        }       
        public static void main(String[]args){
            
            FirstExample.arithmetic();  
        }
    }
    ```
    
           //else{
          //    System.exit(0);
          //     }
         //tried adding this block of code but it gets terminated even after giving 'y/Y'
````

Comment: Use `.equals()` to compare strings in Java.

Comment: `else { break; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
   break;
}
```

There's a few things here.

- First, like mentioned already, use .equals() or .equalsIgnoreCase() to compare strings in java.
- Second, to get out of while loop break is the easiest thing to do here.
- Third, no need for an else statement as you're only interested in if you need to stop at this point - otherwise you can just continue what you were doing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's exiting even if you enter Y is that comparing `String`s with `==` won't work since its comparing the references to the Strings, not the characters in the Strings. Instead, use the .equals method:

`if(input.equals("y") || input.equals("Y"))`

Comment: Thank u so much for the solution with the explanation, it worked for me and got the reason too@Heng Ye

Comment: @YashDeole If so, you should mark this answer as accepted. Click on the tick ✔ next to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to introduce a boolean flag. So instead of having `while (true)`, it could be refactored to something like:

```java
class FirstExample {
    static void arithmetic() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     
        boolean shouldStop = false;
            
        while(!shouldStop){
            System.out.println("\nDo u want to perform the arithmetic operations? (Y/N): ");
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            
            if ("n".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                shouldStop = true;
            } else if ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
                double first = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
                double second = sc.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Addition of the two number is: "+(first+second));
                System.out.println("Subtraction of the two number is: "+(first-second));
                System.out.println("Multiplication of the two number is: "+(first*second));
                System.out.println("Division of the two number is: "+(first/second));
                sc.nextLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, two more comments (some already pointed out):

1. use `equals(String)`, or `equalsIgnoreCase(String)` (to be case insensitive) instead of `==`. An example on `equalsIgnoreCase` can be found [here](https://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/string/string_equalsignorecase.php).
2. you could call `equals()` (or `equalsIgnoreCase()`) on the string literal, rather than the variable; this is to avoid null pointer exceptions. So instead of doing `input.equalsIgnoreCase("n)` you could do `"n".equalsIgnoreCase(input)`, in case `input` is `null`. You could read more [on this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20385179/calling-equals-on-string-literal)

Comment: what's the point of the flag if you're anyway using break to get out of the loop? why not just while(true) with the break?

Comment: That is correct; thanks for pointing it out :) I had that break there by mistake. I've edited the answer accordingly.